# If I want to show 2.01:30:00 as 49:30 what is the suitable string format in Silverlight 5?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-5.0

If I want to show 2.01:30:00 as 49:30 what is the suitable string format?

Comment: maybe I am just being a noob but I cant see what is the translation logic you are using to convert 2.01:30 to 49:30

Comment: @Techmonk - it's a time span of 2 days, 1 hour and 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant but this C# works:

```
((int)time.TotalHours).ToString() + ":" +
((int)(time.TotalMinutes - (int)time.TotalHours * 60)).ToString()
```

So you'll have to write a converter that takes in your TimeSpan and output this string:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        var time = (TimeSpan)value;
        return ((int)time.TotalHours).ToString() + ":" +
               ((int)(time.TotalMinutes - (int)time.TotalHours * 60)).ToString();
    }
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding theTimeSpan, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}} />
```